# Click frequency calculation

Tags: javascript, frequency

I'm trying to come up with a method for calculating frequency of an action, to be more specific, mouse clicks.

This is what I have in my head (im not the best a maths or explaining but I'll try).

I expect a user to be able to reach an average click frequency of 10 clicks per second and I want to know what percentage of that target was achieved per 1 10th of a second. I am nearly there... I think but because I set the mouse clicks back down to 0, the frequency drops straight down instead of declining gradually...

This is where I'm at but I'm not thinking clear at the moment :-)

```
var frequency = function( maxFrequency, milliseconds, callback ) {
    var mouseDown = 0;
    var loopCount = 1;
    var frequentTap = new taps( $(window), 'frequency', function() {
        mouseDown++;
    });
    var loop = setInterval( function() {
        callback( mouseDown / ( maxFrequency ) );
        if( loopCount % 10 === 0 ) mouseDown = 0;
        loopCount++;
    }, milliseconds );
    this.stop = function(){
        clearInterval( loop );
    }
};

frequency( 10, 100, function( freq ) {
    console.log(freq);
});
```

dont worry about the tabs function, just assume it tracks clicks.

any help is very much appreciated

regards

**EDIT:**

created a plugin if anyone requires it: http://luke.sno.wden.co.uk/v8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking about this in a slightly different way--you could store timestamps at which the mouse was clicked, and then do your calculation based on the timestamps you have stored.

Runnable example below:

```js
var frequency = function(maxFrequency, milliseconds, updateFrequency, callback ) {
  var timeTotal = 0;
  var clickTimes = [];
  var numberOfMilliseconds = milliseconds;

  document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime(); //get time in ms

    //add the current time to the array and the counter
    timeTotal += currentTime;
    clickTimes.push(currentTime);
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime(); //get time in ms

    //remove any items that occurred more than milliseconds limit ago
    while(clickTimes.length && (currentTime - clickTimes[0] > milliseconds)) {
      timeTotal -= clickTimes.shift();
    }

    if (clickTimes.length > 0) {
      numberOfMilliseconds = clickTimes[clickTimes.length - 1] - clickTimes[0];
    } else {
      numberOfMilliseconds = milliseconds;
    }

    callback(numberOfMilliseconds, clickTimes.length, (clickTimes.length * 100 / maxFrequency).toFixed(0)); 
  }, updateFrequency);
};

frequency(10, 1000, 100, function(milliseconds, numberOfClicks, targetPercentage) {
  document.getElementById("numberOfMilliseconds").innerHTML = milliseconds;
  document.getElementById("numberOfClicks").innerHTML = numberOfClicks;
  document.getElementById("targetPercentage").innerHTML = targetPercentage;
});
```

```html
<h1>Click anywhere in the document</h1>
You've clicked <span id="numberOfClicks">0</span> times in the past <span id="numberOfMilliseconds">0</span> milliseconds<br/>
This is <span id="targetPercentage">0</span>% of your target.
```

Comment: !! howd you make it runnable! I understand the above but it doesn't give me the desired results.. let me see if I can clear it up a little.

Comment: @LukeSnowden http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/. Also let me know your desired results and maybe I can help you further. I just made it count the number of clicks in the past 1 second maximum.

Comment: Right, added it to my answer, run it, click as many times as you can, that pretty much what im after but I know it isn't correct mathematically

Comment: I think I finally understand what you are looking for. Updated my answer.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what im looking for. Going to look through this later and see where i was going wrong. cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Right, I'm not sure on the math on this one but I think I have managed to achieve the desired effect here:

```js
var frequency = function(actionTarget, milliseconds, callback) {
  var mouseDown = 0;
  $(window).click(function() {
    if (mouseDown < actionTarget) mouseDown++;
  });
  var loop = setInterval(function() {
    callback(mouseDown / (actionTarget));
    mouseDown -= (1 - (actionTarget / milliseconds));
    if (mouseDown < 0) mouseDown = 0;
  }, milliseconds);
  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(loop);
  }
};


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  frequency(10, 100, function(freq) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Number(freq).toFixed(2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```