# Listen for multiple events in a specified period of time

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Is there is a way to listen for multiple events on an HTML element in a certain period of time using JavaScript?

For example, I want to see if the user clicks an element 5 times within 2500 milliseconds or something like that.

I am unable to go into a lot of detail currently. If need be I can put more detail in once I have more time.

I am thinking just a click event on an HTML element that updates the number of clicks each click and then resets a timer if the specified number of clicks has not been reached within a specified time period. I have tried some ways of accomplishing this and they have all failed.

I would prefer it be pure JavaScript, however I could use jQuery as a last resort.

If there is a completely obvious answer to this question I apologize ahead of time.

This is different from [Click frequency calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495225/click-frequency-calculation) because I don't care about frequency too much. I care that a user clicked a few times in a certain period and only then run some code. I also would prefer to not use `setInterval()`. The two questions are certainly related, but I wouldn't say they are duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click frequency calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495225/click-frequency-calculation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method doesn't require any Jquery or make use of any timers, which as an  added bonus, makes it much more accurate.

```js
var clicks = 0,
    firstClickTime = 0,
    clicksNeeded = 3,
    timeSpan = 1000; //time in milliseconds

var myEvent = function(){
  document.getElementById("myLabel").innerHTML="TRIGGERED!";
}

document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function(){
  var dt = Date.now()-firstClickTime;
  if ( dt > timeSpan){
    firstClickTime=Date.now();
    clicks = 0;
  }
  if (++clicks >= clicksNeeded){
    firstClickTime=0;
    clicks=0;
    myEvent();
  }
};
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Test</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="document.getElementById('myLabel').innerHTML='Not Triggered';clicks=0;firstClickTime=0;">Reset</button>
<h1 id="myLabel">Not Triggered</h1>
```